# Msbuild usando Jenkins en Servidor Linux

Tags: linux, jenkins

Chicos, tengo un servidor de ic en linux, y tengo que buildear un proyecto en .net, pero todo lo que veo es que el msbuild se usa solo en servidores windows, este se puede usar en linux o hay algo lo mas parecido a msbuild para hacerlo

Answer (score 1):

Actualmente algunos binarios de .net se pueden usar en linux: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial (en la parte izquierda seleccionas la distribución) lo que puedes hacer es ejecutar a través de un shell la compilación del proyecto.